# Why do only some languages have different words for calling a married and unmarried women?

Tags: historical-linguistics

English language has Miss and Missis for referring to unmarried and married women. German has Frau and Fräulein. What caused such words to appear in some languages and not in others?

Comment: @user6726 if asking why certain words (don't) exist in certain languages is bad to the point that it's funny and warrants mocking, I'd like to know why.

Comment: A word of warning: Don't say `Fräulein` in German. I did once, but I think I got away with it.

Comment: @user1306322 If the point of your question is why this distinction is handled differently in different languages, you could change your title to "Why do *only some* languages have..."

Comment: It is indeed my point. Also, I'm not a native English speaker, if that's what can help make this question more legitimate.

Comment: @user6726 The validity of that question does not invalidate this one. That said, I think a great answer would address both and the underlying presuppositions. If you're prepared to craft such an answer, I would be interested to read it.

Comment: The first version of the question was better. To notice a pattern and merely ask “why” is more general, neutral and carries less assumptions. To add the word “only” can be seen to imply that it is expected that all languages would. This is a question that should not involve any controversy at all. Because it is about women and marriage it appears a commenter infers a negative attitude in the question, yet the question does not necessitate any sexist undertones, but merely asks how some languages came to fundamentally differentiate between two things that in other languages are considered one.